# How to respond an email for postdoc process

Tags: postdocs

I live in Iraq and my postdoc application for a Dutch position has been accepted. Now, the PI has sent me an email:

> Dear XXX,
>
> Ms YYY (in Cc) and Ms ZZZ will now start the procedure of your
> appointment. Please let us know from which date you can be available.
> Note that it may take about two months to arrange your residence
> permit.
>
> Kind regards,

I have ambiguity about the sentence:

> which date you can be available?

Does she mean the date on which I can start the job (for example as soon as my visa gets ready) or she means the day on which I will be available for HR calls? (for example tomorrow)

Thank you.

Comment: It's fine to email the professor to clarify, if you aren't sure (and not just about hiring-related matters).

Comment: My read on it is what date you can start, particularly since the next sentence is about how long it could take to get a residence permit in place (needed to start).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Congratulations on your new job!

They want to know at which day you can start the job, in order to include the starting date in your contract, which I presume ms. YYY and ZZZ are drawing up as we speak.

Comment: +1 for the congratulations.

Comment: Also the reason for such phrasing is, usually people are busy, they cannot leave at any time, maybe you work contract requires you to serve 3 month notices, so they are asking you when you want/can start to work for them.

Answer (score 12):

I would interpret this as: which date is it possible for you to come to the Netherlands to start the job.

But I think the best approach is to give a slightly more details on when you are available for what.  You could say "I'm available to discuss any issues around setting up on the job on X and Y days, between Z and W hours.  I'll be ready to move to the Netherlands whenever my permit is ready/any time after April 12/let me get back to you in a week or two with a precise date."

Comment: Also, you're communicating with dutch people, don't be afraid to be direct and not superfluous in wording things. Respectful but direct.